# I need help with multiple integrals!

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to compute the this integral: $$\iiint_Vz^3dxdydz$$ on $$z\le4-x^2-y^2, \ z\ge0,\ z\le 3$$

I don't understand how to do this, please help

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
We have
$$V =\big\{(x,y,z)\in \Bbb R^3\mid z \leq 4-x^2-y^2,0 \leq z \leq 3\big\}=\big\{(x,y,z)\in \Bbb R^3\mid x^2+y^2 \leq 4-z,0 \leq z \leq 3\big\}$$
Set $x = r\cos(\theta)$ and $y = r\sin(\theta)$, then $x^2+y^2=r^2$ and thus
$$V = \big\{(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta),z)\in \Bbb R^3\mid 0\leq z \leq 3, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi,0\leq r \leq \sqrt{4-z}\big\}.$$

Comment: after I calculate by cylindric formula, I still don't get the answer

Comment: I have: $81/2(4-z)\pi$

Comment: @tmac_balla It is not cylindric formula here because $r \neq z$... $81/2(4-z)\pi$ is not possible because your answer shouldn't depend on $z$...